# Subset data frame with matrix of logical values

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, subset, logical-operators

**Problem**

I have data on two measures for four individuals each in a wide format. The measures are `x` and `y` and the individuals are `A, B, C, D`. The data frame looks like this

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 40, replace = F), ncol = 8))
colnames(d) <- paste(rep(c("x.", "y."),each = 4), rep(LETTERS[1:4], 2), sep ="")
d

  x.A x.B x.C x.D y.A y.B y.C y.D
1  56  65  42  96 100  76  39  26
2  19  93  94  75  63  78   5  44
3  22  57  15  62   2  29  89  79
4  49  13  95  97  85  81  60  37
5  45  38  24  91  23  82  83  72
```

Now, would I would like to obtain for each row is the value of `y` for the individual with the lowest value of `x`.

So in the example above, the lowest value of `x` in row `1` is for individual `C`. Hence, for row `1` I would like to obtain `y.C` which is `39`.

In the example, the resulting vector should be `39, 63, 89, 81, 83`.

**Approach**

I have tried to get to this by first generating a matrix of the subset of `d` for the values of `x`.

```
t(apply(d[,1:4], 1, function(x) min(x) == x))

       x.A   x.B   x.C   x.D
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now I wanted to apply this matrix to subset the subset of the data frame for the values of `y`. But I cannot find a way to achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated. Suggestions for a totally different - more elegant - approach are highly welcome too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can subset the set of `y` values directly with the Boolean mask: `d[,5:8][t(apply(d[,1:4], 1, function(x) min(x) == x))]`

Comment: You can check the solution below.  It should be faster compared to the `apply` method in your post

Comment: @alistaire  That method wouldn't give the expected output in the correct order.  I would use `t(d[,5:8])[apply(d[,1:4], 1, function(x) min(x) == x)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subset the dataset with the columns starting with 'x' ('dx') and 'y' ('dy').  Get the column index of the minimum value in each row of 'dx' using `max.col`, `cbind` with the row index and get the corresponding elements in 'dy'.

```
 dx <- d[grep('^x', names(d))]
 dy <- d[grep('^y', names(d))]
 dy[cbind(1:nrow(dx),max.col(-dx, 'first'))]
 #[1] 39 63 89 81 83
```

The above can be easily be converted to a function

```
 get_min <- function(dat){
     dx <- dat[grep('^x', names(dat))]
     dy <- dat[grep('^y', names(dat))]
     dy[cbind(1:nrow(dx), max.col(-dx, 'first'))]
   }
get_min(d)
#[1] 39 63 89 81 83
```

---

Or using the OP's `apply` based method

```
t(d[,5:8])[apply(d[,1:4], 1, function(x) min(x) == x)] 
#[1] 39 63 89 81 83
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(x.A = c(56L, 19L, 22L, 49L, 45L),
x.B = c(65L, 
93L, 57L, 13L, 38L), x.C = c(42L, 94L, 15L, 95L, 24L), 
x.D = c(96L, 
75L, 62L, 97L, 91L), y.A = c(100L, 63L, 2L, 85L, 23L), 
y.B = c(76L, 
78L, 29L, 81L, 82L), y.C = c(39L, 5L, 89L, 60L, 83L), 
y.D = c(26L, 
44L, 79L, 37L, 72L)), .Names = c("x.A", "x.B", "x.C", 
"x.D", 
"y.A", "y.B", "y.C", "y.D"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `max.col` was new to me. Though I prefer the one-line approach using `apply`. Given the size of my data frame, performance is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The core idea is that there are functions `which.min, which.max` that can be row applied to the data frame:

Edit:

> Now, would I would like to obtain for each row is the value of y for
>   the individual with the lowest value of x.

```
ind <- apply(d[ ,1:4], 1, which.min) # build column index by row
res <- d[,5:8][cbind(1:nrow(d), ind)] # rows are in order, select values by matrix
names(res) <- colnames(d)[5:8][ind] # set colnames as names from the sample column
res 
y.D y.B y.D y.A y.D
18  46  16  85  80
```

Caveat: only works if individuals are in the same order for treatment x. and y. and all individuals present. Otherwise you can use grep like in Akrun's solution.

```
# My d was:

   x.A x.B x.C x.D y.A y.B y.C y.D
1  88  96  65  55  14  99  63  18
2  12  11  27  45  70  46  20  69
3  32  81  21   9  77  44  91  16
4   8  84  42  78  85  94  28  90
5  31  51  83   2  67  25  54  80
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function as follows,

```
get_min <- function(x){
  d1 <- x[,1:4]
  d2 <- x[,5:8]
  mtrx <- as.matrix(d2[,apply(d1, 1, which.min)])
  a <- row(mtrx) - col(mtrx)
  split(mtrx, a)$"0" 
}
get_min(d)
#[1] 39 63 89 81 83
```