# Apply a dataframe of boolean values onto another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as such:

```
| x | y |
|---|---|
| a | e |
| b | f |
| c | g |
| d | h |
```

and I have a dataframe of bool values as such:

```
| x     | y     |
|-------|-------|
| FALSE | TRUE  |
| FALSE | TRUE  |
| TRUE  | FALSE |
| TRUE  | FALSE |
```

(actually this stuff came out as a result from [a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728123/comparing-two-similar-dataframes-and-finding-different-values-between-them), but that's not really relevant cos this is a stand-alone question)

I'm just searching for a way to apply the df with the bool values to the 'regular' df, and get this:

```
| x | y |
|---|---|
|   | e |
|   | f |
| c |   |
| d |   |
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887997/subset-data-frame-with-matrix-of-logical-values) asked a very similar question, but the solutions diverged into different directions.

I have tried a wide variety of different indexing schemes, but they all fail to retain the rectangular structure of the output that I desire.

`df[mask]` was too good to be true as well.

Any advice much appreciated.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  y = c('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), stringsAsFactors = F
)

mask <- structure(list(x = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), y = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you expecting those blank values in your output?

Comment: Blank or NA or whatever is handy...

Comment: `df$x <- ifelse(mask$x, df$x, ""); df$y <- ifelse(mask$y, df$y, "")` will work in this simple case

Comment: @SymbolixAU that is a really good approach. I should have thought of thattttt...

Comment: Didn't you already got the answer in you previous post both under comments and the answer? How is this question differ?

Answer (score 9):

The simplest approach is (thanks to @thelatemail for inspiration)

```
df[!mask] <- ""
#   x y
# 1   e
# 2   f
# 3 c  
# 4 d
```

Which works because `!` coerces `mask` to a logical matrix (so there's no need for the `as.matrix()` call)

```
str(mask)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ x: logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#   $ y: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE

str(!mask)
# logi [1:4, 1:2] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"

## and
class(!mask)
# "matrix"
```

A couple of `ifelse`s will also work

```
df$x <- ifelse(mask$x, df$x, "")
df$y <- ifelse(mask$y, df$y, "")
```

Comment: You don't even have to convert `df` to a matrix first explicitly - `replace(df, as.matrix(mask), NA)`, equivalent to `df[as.matrix(mask)] <- NA`

Comment: @thelatemail - very nice - I spend most of my time working with `data.table` that I often forget `base` syntax

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through the columns with `mapply`, examining the values in `mask`:

```
as.data.frame( mapply(function(x,y) ifelse(y, x, ''), df, mask))
##   x y
## 1   e
## 2   f
## 3 c  
## 4 d
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(df, !mask, "")
#  x y
#1   e
#2   f
#3 c  
#4 d
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer if needing to mask values only in certain columns of a dataframe, e.g. `df[,cols.to.mask] <- replace(df[,cols.to.mask], mask, NA)`.